# MongoDB C# driver - Obsolete CountAsync method is around 6 time faster then CountDocumentAsync. Why?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection with only 1.2M records and I need to perform two count queries. One without any filter and one with a filter on a indexed `date` type field.

I am using the `C#` driver and for some reason the fastest results I got was using the `CountAsync` method.

Results were:

`CountAsync` was the fastest by far, but this method is marked as obsolete.
`CountDocumentAsync` was around 6 times slower than `CountAsync`.
Using aggregation was around 10-15 times slower than `CountAsync`.

Any idea why an obsolete method is the faster way to count documents in a collection?

Side note -
Within the aggregation I used the following:

Count without filter used `$count` aggregation pipeline stage
Count with filter used `$match` than `$count` pipeline stages.

Answer (score 2):

To have the closest behavior than CountAsync you can use EstimatedDocumentCountAsync

When you turn log on you can see the queries are different:

```
var count1 = await cnx.GetDatabase("flow").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Page")
  .CountAsync(_ => true);
query = { "count" : "Page", "query" : { }, "$db" : "flow" }

var count2 = await cnx.GetDatabase("flow").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Page")
  .EstimatedDocumentCountAsync();
query = { "count" : "Page", "$db" : "flow" }

var count3 = await cnx.GetDatabase("flow").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Page")
  .CountDocumentsAsync(_=>true);
query = { "aggregate" : "Page", "pipeline" : [{ "$match" : { } }, { "$group" : { "_id" : 1, "n" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }], "cursor" : { }, "$db" : "flow" }
```